# Parse a date string from a twitter post with timezone info included

Tags: dart

I have created a tweet using Twitters REST API. The returned JSON from Twitter from the created Tweet is in this format

```
'Tue Jan 31 11:15:15 +0000 2017'
```

Darts

```
DateTime.parse('Tue Jan 31 11:15:15 +0000 2017');
```

won't parse this format. I turned to the ***intl*** package holds some hope in dealing with this. I try to use `DateFormat` to solve this thus

```
DateFormat format = new DateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy");
format.parse('Tue Jan 31 11:15:15 +0000 2017');
```

It fails. The only way I can get it to work is to remove the timezone part of the twitter date string

```
'Tue Jan 31 11:15:15 2017'
```

and do the following

```
var date = 'Tue Jan 31 11:15:15 +0000 2017'.split(' ');
date.removeAt(4);
DateFormat format = new DateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
format.parse(date.join(' '));
```

How can I parse a Twitter datetime string without removing the timezone info part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `package:intl` doesn't support timezones yet: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/128

You could add your use case to the issue (it shouldn't be much work or require extra data to support the 'ZZZZ' case, since you just need to parse a number), or even better, submit a Pull Request!

Answer (score 3):

Dart DateTime doesn't support timezones, so it's not that useful to parse them. Also, Intl is probably not the best way to parse a string like this. The point of Intl date parsing is that it varies by locale. If you want to parse a fixed format it can be done more easily and more efficiently.

Since DateTime doesn't support time zones, if you want to use that information, it seems like your best bet is to remove it, get the information, and then add that to the time after the fact.

If you're running in the browser, you could also call out to the JS Date.parse(), which does handle that format.

Comment: I was wanting to parse the date string directly and not have to implement my own parser.  DateTime doesn't parse things like Jan, etc. While I could write something to change that to something DateTime will accept, I don't want to. That's why package:intl was so attractive to me, because it does handle things like Jan.  Thanks for pointing out the JS Date.parse, though I am wanting to do this server side too.